# How do I make the label in polar chart not get split automatically?

Tags: highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/7rLnwdxu/1/

here is the code.

I want to make all the labels behave just like the Word1_Word2 one (stay in one line). Even when there is (space) or `-` between them.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the labels' style object to pass css to control this

```
labels: {
  style: {
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
  }
}
```

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/7rLnwdxu/2/

**EDIT**

In order to 1) accommodate more complex requirements of the labels that might arise, and 2) be more inline with the upcoming Highcharts 5 release, which will separate style and content, you can do this by

1) setting useHTML: true in the axis label properties

2) assigning a common label class to the html element that will contain your labels, and

3) use external CSS to specify all of the required styling.

**Example, Chart code:**

```
labels: {
  useHTML: true,
  formatter: function() {
    return '<div class="category-label">'+this.value+'</div>'
  }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.category-label {
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Updated fiddle:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/7rLnwdxu/6/

Comment: Just add all of the relevant styles to the label style object:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/7rLnwdxu/4/, **OR**, set *useHTML* true on the label, if you can't accommodate all of your needs that way: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/7rLnwdxu/5/

Comment: Updated answer with more detail

Comment: On a side note, although they seem to be growing in popularity again for some reason, these radar charts are generally a poor way to show this data. Comparisons of this nature are much easier and much more clear with a simple column chart, or better yet, a bullet graph ( http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yayrwsx7/ ). FWIW.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Now totally meets what I want. Just wondering, why radar charts are poor way to show data? Is there any data/evidence or just a personal preference?

Comment: They artificially complicate the comparison between the two series, and they completely obscure any trends in time series data. Nothing is gained by wrapping the data around a circle, but perceptually and cognitively, much is usually lost (obviously specific cases can be exceptions, but those are rare). A bullet graph, or simply a bar with a target marker, makes comparisons of budget to actual extremely simple to perceive, and compare across categories.

Comment: An example of your chart as a column with targets: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/7rLnwdxu/7/

Comment: Thanks very much! Very insightful.

Comment: I still have a question about the radar chart labels. Is it possible to dynamically change the style of some specified label. For example, what if I want to make the "Word1_Word2" in red in the example above? Thanks!

Comment: If you have a known circumstance that will trigger the custom styling (such as the category name), you can add a check to the formatter function to add additional classes to the label element, and style those classes accordingly. There is also a recent question that dealt with coloring an axis label based on a click event, that you can search for if you need something more dynamic